# How can i get my data from headers in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt

I'm learning nodejs. Actually I'm trying to write AUTH with Jwt token. I can generate token and save it in headers.

```
     router.post('/login', async(req, res) => {
      const {username, password } = req.body;
      const user = await Users.findOne({ where: {name: username}})
      if (!user) res.json({error: "Users doesnt exist"});
      
      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then((match) => {
        if (!match) res.json({error: "Wrong username and password combination"})
        const accessToken = sign({name: user.username, id: user.id}, "tajneheslo", {expiresIn: "2h"}); 
        res.setHeader('accessToken', accessToken);
        
    });
      
});
```

but after that i'm stuck. I dont know how can i get data from headers. In middleware for example. I'm beginner so please don't judge me.

Answer (score 1):

You can access to token with : req.headers.authorization
and example of writing a middleWare not the best not the cleanest is code below :

```js
const authenticateMiddleWare = async (req, res, next)=> {
  try {
    const authorization = (req.headers.authorization ||
      req.headers.Authorization)
    if (!authorization) {
      throw new Error('there is no bearer token in the headers')
    }

    const accessToken = authorization.split(' ')[1]
    const jwt = verify(
      jwtToken,
      'tajneheslo' //YOUR_JWT_SECRET
    )
    const user = await Users.findOne({ where: {_id: jwt.id}})
    if(!user) throw new Error('Ooops user not found')
    //put the data you need in res.locals or re.user or any other convention 
    //as a example : 
    res.user = {
      userId: user.id,
      username: user.username,
      //or any other data you need in your controller
    }
    //then you can have access to this data any where you have access to res
    //use this middleware on any route you want
    next() //pass it 
  } catch (error) {
    //log or console your error for better traceability
    console.log('error in authenticate middleWare : ', error)
    res.status(401).send('UNAUTHORIZED')
  }
}
```

in the next step you can use redis for advance scenarios like revoking an access token or set an expiration time and ...

Answer (score 0):

You can get headers by using req.headers which will give all the headers as an object. Then you can get the value accessToken by req.headers.accessToken.